# Категория по умолчанию

Tags: wordpress

Создал пользовательский тип записи "Отзывы". И есть у меня несколько рубрик: ру1, ру2, ру3. Как сделать, чтобы при добавлении новой пользовательской записи "Отзывы", галка принадлежности к категории ру3 уже стояла автоматом?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте использовал хук `save_post`:

```
<?php
function save_custom_post ( $post_id, $post = null ) {
    if ( ! $post ) $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts', $post->ID ) ) return;
    if ( 'Отзывы' != $post->post_type ) return;
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, 'Ваш терм', 'Ваша таксономия' );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_post', 10, 2 );
```